# how-to assembly simple standalone function for win32, which assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

much tnx for help

I want to assembly some simple function like

```
    struct float3
    {
     float x;
     float y;
     float z;
    };

    inline float dot(float3* a, float3* b)
    {
      return (*a).x * (*b).x + (*a).y * (*b).y + (*a).z * (*b).z;
    }
```

or yet simpler for the beginning

```
    int add(int a, int b) 
    { 
      return a + b; 
    }
```

I need to write it in x86 assembly and produce .obj file to link
it and call from c code

1) assembler should be free of charge and free to use
2) it should assemble x86 for win32
3) should be able to produce older omf obj binary (this maybe i can skip because
possibly i could convert coff to omf with some tool objnonv by agner fog, maybe)
4) should support new instruction sets - at least sse but better avx also

also i need an example how tu write such function, under it, and how to
assemble it to obj

much tnx, 
fir

[edit]

i have found partial solution - in nasm i can assemble

```
    segment _TEXT public align = 1 class = CODE use32

    global  asm_main

    asm_main:
    enter   0,0
    pusha
    ;---------------------------
    ;
    ;
    ;----------------------------
    popa
    mov     eax, 2324            ; return back to C
    leave
    ret
```

in c i can use it

```
    extern "C" int __cdecl asm_main(void);

    int ret_status = asm_main();  //gets 2324 as i want
```

but i have next error when i am trying to add data section before the rest

```
    segment _DATA public align = 4 class = DATA use32

    txt1 db    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 0
    txt2 db    "yyyyyyyyyyyyy", 0
```

i have error from my old borland c++ 5.5.1 compiler

```
    Fatal: 'myasm.obj': Additional segments need to be defined in a .def file
```

doeas anyone know what i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASM is by far the best assembler for Windows. NASM is much more Linux oriented.

A structure is written in form:

```
FLOAT3 STRUCT
    x DWORD ?
    y DWORD ?
    z DWORD ?
FLOAT3 ENDS
```

Because I am much more familiar with nasm, the add function would look like this:

EDITED:

assume we have another rutine, that want to print hello world on the screen ( this is a linux rutine!)

```
segment .data

text dw "hello",10,0 ; dw stans for define word
text_len EQU $ - text ; get the length of text

segment .text
extern _add
extern print

print:    ; not exportable to C in this format
    mov eax,4 ; 4 indices we what to write
    mov ebx,1 ; 1 indicated standard output
    mov ecx,text ; address of text is now in registe ecx
    mov edx,text_len ; value of text len is now in register edx
    int 80H ; now we call the kernel

    mov eax,1 ; last 3 lines enable us to exit the program normally. 
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 80H




_add:
   enter 0,0
   mov eax,[ebp+8]  ; first argument
   mov ebx,[ebp+12]  ; second argument
   add eax,ebx
   leave
   ret
```

you can assemble it using nasm -f win32 first.asm

then declare the prototype in c **extern**

Comment: tnx much, i will try it, can you maybe show me also the use of ram data (data section) in this snippet? i will check if i still have my linker error with that

Comment: I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: i will check it; need a rest for a while because i was much tired with linker error

Comment: got the same linker error 'Fatal: `fir.asm': Additional segments need to be defined in a .def file`

Comment: resolved it ! - it was -f win32 switch (instead of my -f obj - that caused error) needed only later convert from coff to omf with underscored

Answer (score 1):

[NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) is the best i've used so far. Look here for [OMF](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) support.
About linking Assembly code to C++ you can look here [link](http://www.cs.uakron.edu/~margush/306old/LinkingWithCplusplus.html)

Comment: i had tried nasm a 2 hours ago, but had not found how to write such function and how to 'make it ready' for linking to c (how export function name); can someone link me or writte such int myAdd(int a, int b) code in nasm or other that would be ready for link from c prog

Comment: @user982377 you could look at [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B_to_ASM_linkage_in_GCC) for insight.

Answer (score 1):

Use MASM which is a free download or part of MS Visual Studio:

http://www.masm32.com/masmdl.htm

There is a command line option to export the object file needed to link your function to other applications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0ksfwcf(v=vs.80).aspx

Or you can just create a DLL and link it as usual.